# Although I have defined ORG 7C00, ISO file shows D800

Tags: x86, kernel, nasm, bootloader, osdev

I'm trying to develop a bootloader. But there was one part I didn't understand. I knew that when ORG 7C00 was defined in my assembly file, the program would be loaded at disk 7C00. I compiled it as binary and created the iso file in Magic ISO. Then, when I looked at the hexadecimal version of the ISO file, I saw that the code I wrote started at the D800 address. Shouldn't it be installed at 7C00?

```
org 0x7C00
bits 16

start:
    cli

times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFVDE.png

I also have another question. There is another bootloader signature at address D010. Why?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyZgl.png

Also, there is one more thing I want to know. I want to place some files in my ISO file and I want to read these files at this level. I do my experiments in VirtualBox. How do I read the files inside the ISO file. Or how do I run a program. So what I want to do is to place the kernel here and load it from the bootloader.

If I'm wrong, is there a resource detailing how the bootloaders are loaded and how the BIOS loads?

Comment: VirtualBox is a nightmare to work with for kernel development. Iso files are a byte by byte copy of an optical disk. There is no reason to require a file extension. VirtualBox is a bad piece of very useless software. There is nothing that VirtualBox does that QEMU doesn't but 100 times better. That's also not considering what QEMU can do that VirtualBox never could. QEMU takes a raw file as an hard-drive. To be expected since.. hard-drives store raw bytes afaik. Also VirtualBox is very slow and has a bad command line integration. What takes 1 second with QEMU takes 30 mins with VBox.

Comment: Basically, switch to Linux and QEMU to make it worth your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I knew that when ORG 7C00 was defined in my assembly file, the program would be loaded at disk 7C00.

The `ORG 0x7C00` tells the assembler that it should assume the code will be running with that starting address. It doesn't guarantee that the code will actually be run at that starting address.

> Then, when I looked at the hexadecimal version of the ISO file, I saw that the code I wrote started at the D800 address. Shouldn't it be installed at 7C00?

Files don't have addresses, they have offsets. You'd hope that your code will be loaded from "offset 0xD800 in the file" to "address 0x7C00 in RAM".

> There is another bootloader signature at address D010. Why?

For a bootable CD-ROM (according to my vague memory of the relevant specs); sectors are 2048 bytes, the first 16 sectors are unused and should just be zeros, then at some point after that there's a list of "boot records". The firmware is supposed to check these records to determine what to boot (e.g. so you can have one boot loader for PowerPC, one for 80x86, one for Itanium, ... and the firmware will automatically choose whichever boot loader makes sense). That 0xAA55 is part of it (but I can't remember if it's for each entry, or at the end of the list of all entries).

Note that if your boot record says "80x86, no emulation, load segment in memory = 0x1234" then the BIOS will load a whole boot loader file, won't care if there's an unnecessary 0xAA55 signature anywhere in that file, and will load it into the requested segment in memory; and that "segment in memory" is the only thing that determine the address your code is loaded (and needs to match the ORG you told the assembler in an "load_address = load_segment_in_boot_record * 16 + 0 = unknown_segment * 16 + ORG_from_assembler" way).

Alternatively; if your boot record says "emulate a floppy" or "emulate a hard disk" then the firmware will do what it's told, including the inefficient "read a 2048-byte sector and discard 75% of it to pretend sectors are 512 bytes" stuff), and including loading it at the address 0x00007C00. Of course this was intended as a work-around for ancient operating systems (e.g. MS-DOS) that were written before CD-ROM existed and couldn't have supported booting from CD-ROM properly.

> If I'm wrong, is there a resource detailing how the bootloaders are loaded and how the BIOS loads?

For booting from CD-ROM; the document you want is "El Torito Bootable CD-ROM Format Specification Version 1.0, January 25, 1995" (easy to find from a web search, possibly here: https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2018/readings/boot-cdrom.pdf ).

For booting network you want the the PXE Specification (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment - there's a link at the bottom).

For booting from floppy and hard drive there's "inherited behavior passed from one generation to the next" (and no official specification); but it's covered by about 5 thousand different tutorials that are all slightly wrong.

For booting from USB flash; there's no specification and a horrible mess ("heuristical hackery" done by firmware to try to decide if it should behave like a floppy with a BPB and no partitions or behave like a hard drive with partitions and no BPB; combined with firmware specific quirks).

Of course it's 2022 now, so it's probably a better idea to throw all this in the trash and only support UEFI, where everything is adequately specified.

Comment: One sector is 512 bytes in size and my bootloader is located in the first sector. But when I open the iso file, my bootloader code is not in the first 512 bytes of the file, but at the address D800. Shouldn't the first sector be 0000h? Shouldn't the BIOS bootloader look for it there? but my code is showing on D800.

Comment: @ali:  Assuming you're using the "emulate a hard drive" option; your boot loader is in a fake 512 byte sector at the start of a fake hard drive image, and that hard drive image could be almost anywhere on the CD. One sector on CD is 2048 bytes. The first 16 (2048 byte) sectors of a CD should be zeros; then there's a few sectors used for meta-data, then there's the boot records; then the remainder of the disk is space that could be used for directories, file data, your hard drive image/your boot sector, etc.  0xD800 / 2048 = the 28th sector, which sound about right to me.

Comment: @ali: If you like, you can think of it like eating a banana at the start of lunch. The banana is at the start (of lunch) but isn't at the start (of the day). In the same way, your boot loader is at the start (of a hard drive image) but is not at the start (of the CD).

Comment: Where does the bios find the bootloader if my bootloader is anywhere on the disk. Does it find the line ending with 55AA and go back 510 bytes and load from that address? If so, there may be more than one 55AA in a disk.

Comment: So what I want to ask is, for example, I converted this bootloader to iso. Then I burned it to USB. This bootloader can be anywhere on the USB. How does the BIOS know where and how to find this bootloader?

Comment: @ali: Booting from USB is "no standard, heuristical hackery". I'd guess your firmware happens to decide it looks like a CD and then follows the "El Torito Bootable CD-ROM Format Specification" to find the boot loader.